# Javascript - How to get number of characters in textbox and use substring to delete

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I want to get the number of characters in a textbox and use substring to remove characters if the number of characters is >= 255

I have the following javascript:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function CheckMaxLength(Object, MaxLen) 
    {
        if (Object.value.length >= MaxLen) { //find textbox and use substring } 

        return (Object.value.length <= MaxLen);
    }
</script>
```

What javascript should I use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this.

```
   function CheckMaxLength(Object, MaxLen) 
    {
        if (Object.value.length >= MaxLen) { //find textbox and use substring } 

        return Object.value.substring(0, 255);
    }
```

If you want to handle this on keypress, paste, focus etc then try this.

```
   var MaxLen = 255;
   $('textboxSelector').bind('keypress focus blur paste', function () {
        if (this.value.length > MaxLen) {
            this.value = this.value.substring(0, MaxLen);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: can you use subsring of 255, when the value length is smaller?

Comment: I think OP's MaxLen is greater than 255. But yes `substring` will return the whole string if string length is less than 255.

Comment: This doesn't appear to work, I need a javascript function that adds MaxLenth to a multiline textbox (this already works) but also stops the user from copying and pasting text more than the MaxLength in the textbox.

Answer (score 2):

The following script attaches a `keyuyp event` to an input control and prevents the user from entering data that is ***great than*** 255 characters in length. This is, most likely, a better solution in that the user won't see his text magically disappear when he `blur`s away...

```
document.getElementbyId('<%= MyControl.ClientID %>').onkeyup(function(){
    if(this.value.length > 255) return false;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

`var string = someString.substring(0, 255)` will simply return up to 255 characters with no need to actually test the string for length. So why not:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function CheckMaxLength(Object, MaxLen) {
        var isOfRequisiteLength = Object.value.length <== MaxLen;
        Object.value = Object.value.substring(0, 255)
        return isOfRequisiteLength;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this code, it will done the job perfectly:

```
<HEAD>

<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
function textCounter(field, countfield, maxlimit) {
if (field.value.length > maxlimit) // if too long...trim it!
field.value = field.value.substring(0, maxlimit);
// otherwise, update 'characters left' counter
else 
countfield.value = maxlimit - field.value.length;
}
</script>

</HEAD>

<BODY>

<!-- textCounter() parameters are:  text field, the count field, max length -->

<center>
<form name=myform action="YOUR-SCRIPT.CGI">
<font size="1" face="arial, helvetica, sans-serif"> ( You may enter up to 1024 characters. )<br>
<textarea name=message wrap=physical cols=28 rows=4 onKeyDown="textCounter(message,remLen,1024);" onKeyUp="textCounter(message,remLen,1024);"></textarea>
<br>
<input readonly type=text name=remLen size=3 maxlength=3 value="1024"> characters left</font>
</form> 

</Body>
```